# Find maximum of a utility function U(h1, h2)

Tags: matlab, loops, max

I have a matlab function that returns the utility value `U(h1, h2)` that depends on the number of work hours for two persons `h1` and `h2`. Each person can work at maximum 3500 hours.

How do I write this code in the best way? For only one person I only loop the function from input value 0 to 3500 into a matrix and find the max value in the matrix. But now I have two values that can take the value 0 to 3500 and want to find the max output from the function based on these values.

I would be very grateful for any help!

edit:
Sorry for late return! I haven't had time to look in to this until now. Anyway, here is the code:

```
function Test

global LocalTaxRate
global StateTax1Rate
global StateTax2Rate

LocalTaxRate = 0.3212; %Average 2017
StateTax1Rate = 0.25;
StateTax2Rate = 0.05;

h = [0 0]; % start value
lb = [0 0]; % lower bound of h
ub = [3500 3500]; % upper bound of h
myFun = @(h) -CalcUFamily(h(1), h(2)); % function to minimize with one input
Uoptimal = fmincon(myFun, [1000 1000], [], [], [], [], lb, ub)

end

function UFamily = CalcUFamily(hh,hw) %h = male, w = wife

(bunch of code until this step, which is the relevant one)

 YearlyWorkIncomeHusband = WageHH * hh;
    C = YearlyWorkIncomeHusband + MonthlyTaxableTransfers * 12 - CalcTaxSwe(YearlyWorkIncomeHusband + MonthlyTaxableTransfers * 12, YearlyWorkIncomeHusband, Age) + MonthlyNonTaxableTransfers * 12; %Netincome husband
    YearlyWorkIncomeWife = WageHW * hw;
    C = C + YearlyWorkIncomeWife + MonthlyTaxableTransfers * 12 - CalcTaxSwe(YearlyWorkIncomeWife + MonthlyTaxableTransfers * 12, YearlyWorkIncomeWife, Age) + MonthlyNonTaxableTransfers * 12; %Netincome husband + wife

    UFamily = alpha1 * log10(C/100000) + alpha11 * (log10(C/100000)^2) ...
        + alpha2 * (log10(T/1000-hh/1000)) + alpha22 * (log10(T/1000-hh/1000))^2 + alpha12 * log10(C/100000) * (log10(T/1000-hh/1000)) * 2 ... %husband
        + alpha3 * (log10(T/1000-hw/1000)) + alpha33 * (log10(T/1000-hw/1000))^2 + alpha13 * log10(C/100000) * (log10(T/1000-hw/1000)) * 2 ... %wife
        + alpha23 * (log10(T/1000-hh/1000)) * (log10(T/1000-hw/1000)) ... %common leisure parameter
        - alpha4 * Psa - bfc * Dw; %Dummies
end
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I have a function like:
max U(h1, h2)

where h1 is work hours person 1 and h2 work hours person 2. I want to max U(h1, h2) based on the limits of h1 and h2: h >_ 0, h <_3500

Answer (score 1):

You can use two approaches two solve your problem:

1. Generate a 2D mesh and find the global maximum

   ```
   [h1, h2] = meshgrid(0:100:3500);
   Uoptimal = max(max(U(h1, h2))
   ```
2. Use a multivariate minimisation solver, such as [`fmincon`](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html)

   ```
   h = [1000 1000]; % start value
   lb = [0 0]; % lower bound of h
   ub = [3500 3500]; % upper bound of h
   Uoptimal = fmincon(@(h1, h2) -U(h1, h2), h, [], [], [], [], lb, ub);
   ```

   Note that I minimise `-U`, which is the same as maximising `U`.

Approach 1 will give you the global maxima, but is rather slow for obtaining an accurate result. Approach 2 is very accurate, but may get stuck at a local maxima, depending on the start value and the convexity of your utility function `U`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out! :)

Comment: Sorry for late feedback! I do not get the function to work. I have a separate function called `function UFamily = CalcUFamily(hh,hw)` (hh = working hours husband and hw = working hours wife) and want to maximize it by choosing hw and hh such that UFamily gets its largest possible value. However, when I use your code to do that it does not work :(

What might I have been doing wrong?

Comment: Normally it should work if you replace `U` with `CalcUFamily`. If not, please edit your question and post what you tried.

Comment: Sorry for late return! I haven't had time to look in to this until now. :( I have posted the relevant parts of the code. The problem is that I just get:

`Local minimum possible. Constraints satisfied.

fmincon stopped because the size of the current step is less than
the default value of the step size tolerance and constraints are 
satisfied to within the default value of the constraint tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>`

Comment: So, he found a solution but it may be a local solution. Using option 1. may give you a global optimum. You can compare both results.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the out values (I should have been clearer, sorry!):

`Uoptimal =

   1.0e+03 *

    1.4616    2.9780`

I want the out values to be the number of working hours (from 0 to 3500) that optimizes the function (utility value), not the utility values. Apart from that I do not think that the code is able to test the utility value for 0 working hours? This part of my code in `UFamily`  is not working if you work 0 hours, thus the optimization code seems not to test the utility value for 0 working hours (I tried to put the start value to 0 in my posted code, didn't work)

Comment: `max` can also return the index (as a second return value), see the documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I'll study it! But I am still wondering why it doesn't start with 0 h? Thanks for all help :)