# Maximizing a function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, maximize

I have a function in matlab called `function UFamily = CalcUFamily(hh,hw)`. The value of the function is determined by hh and hw (working hours for husband and wife in a family). I want to get the hh and hw that maximizes the function `UFamily`.

How shall i proceed? I can't get the `fmincon` to work.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: You need to add your code of how you tried to use `fmincon` and almost definitely need to add more information about (if not code for) `CalcUFamily`

Comment: `h = [1000 1000]; % start value
lb = [0 0]; % lower bound of h
ub = [3500 3500]; % upper bound of h
Uoptimal = fmincon(@(h1, h2) -U(h1, h2), h, [], [], [], [], lb, ub);`

`CalcUFamily` is a very long code, but it is based on the working hours of the female and male in the household.

Comment: Please add the code into the question which you can edit, code in comments like this is unreadable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find maximum of a utility function U(h1, h2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723639/find-maximum-of-a-utility-function-uh1-h2)

Comment: Please do not duplicate your questions. This is one of the worst thing you can do. When you have a follow up question, at least provide a link to your previous question and clearly specify the difference.

Comment: Ok, sorry! Wont do it again

Answer (score 0):

The function for fmincon to minimize should use 'h' (1x2) as its input, while your function CalcUFamily requires two input, hh and hw. You can do something like:

```
myFun = @(h) -CalcUFamily(h(1), h(2)); % function to minimize with one input
Uoptimal = fmincon(myFun, [1000 1000], [], [], [], [], lb, ub);
```

Comment: Thanks! Will this work for testing from 1 hour to 3500 hours for male and female, separately?

Comment: I don't one can answer this, since this is related to how you evaluate it, i.e. how your CalcUFamily function computes the scores.

Comment: I get:

`Error in Berakningsmodeller (line 6)
Uoptimal = fmincon(myFun, [1000 1000], [], [], [], [], lb, ub);

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FMINCON cannot continue.`

Do you need the whole code in my other function? It is long, but I can post it if needs be.

Comment: No need for the whole code, but you need to make sure your CalcUFamily function receives two numbers (hh, hw) as input, and gives output of single number.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out tomorrow again!

Comment: Seems like the code works! Thanks a lot :) One more question, I would need to add some parameters when I call UFamily (like income) that are used in the UFamily function but that are fixed and shall not be optimized. How can I do that?